# How to span cells in GridLayout correctly?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

### Background

I wanted to show a grid of 5 items (each has ImageView and TextView below it), while 3 are in the first row, and 2 are on the second (each row resized the cells accordingly). After I succeed with this, I would want to change a bit the padding and/or marging in some cells, but this shouldn't be an issue.

For this, I tried using a RecyclerView, and it worked really well, but then I've decided that it's not a good solution, because I need it in a ScrollView, which can cause bad nested scrolling behavior, while I need to show all of the grid items together, without scrolling (like a layout).

Since I need to show only 5 items (or even less), I decided to try GridLayout.

### The problem

Looking at the samples of GridLayout, I thought I understood how it works, but it seems I have a weird issue using it.

I'm trying to have a GridLayout with 3 cells on the first row, and 2 cells on the second, all being centered.

For this, I decided to have a column count of 6 (which is divided by 2 and 3), and row count of 2. First row will have cells that each has a span of 2, and for the second row, each cell will have a span of 3.

However, no matter what I do, I fail achieving this simple task.

This is, for example, what I get from the below code:

[image]

The upper row is fine, but the second one has the first item take 2 columns (2/6 = 1/3) , and the other cell takes 4 columns (4/6 = 2/3).

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:columnCount="6"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    app:rowCount="2"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f0f"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00f"
        app:layout_columnSpan="3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

### What I've tried

I tried to use weights instead. I tried to set the exact column and row for each cell. I tried to use the built-in GridLayout instead of the one of the support library, I tried to change the gravity of the cells...

Changing the width of the GridLayout itself to "match_parent" also has its own weird results:

[image]

Changing the width of the cells is even worse.

Of course, I also tried reading more and try out samples.

### The question

What's wrong with the code? Why does it look the way it does?

---

EDIT: found a solution for using RecyclerView. Still, I want to know what's wrong with what I wrote, and learn about GridLayout from this.

Comment: BTW, for now I use RecyclerView, and just set it to have nestedScrollingEnabled to be false, but this doesn't work by itself, and requires the RecyclerView to have a minHeight being set too.

Comment: try `TableLayout`

Comment: @pskink Question is about GridLayout, which is also supposed to be better. I want to understand how to use GridLayout correctly.

Comment: you need a working solution or `GridLayout` is better, even if not working?

Comment: @pskink As I wrote, I want to understand how to use it correctly. This case should be pretty easy to achieve. My current solution already works pretty well (using RecyclerView).

Comment: @pskink Updated question to show that I already have a solution for RecyclerView. It was also written here in the comments.